# Reading a buffered image displays transparency but outputs wrong alpha value

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am trying to load in a file from `JFileChooser` then convert it to `BufferedImage` to crop it. I am detecting the pixel colour of the image to determine where to crop. However, if I input a transparent image, the transparent portion will be considered black and output colour value (0, 0, 0, 255).

I used `ImageIO` to read the file from the file chooser into a buffered image.

```
inputFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

// try and catch to see if file being read exist
try {

    BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

    // the input image is a resized version of the loaded image to fit the button size
    inputImage = CustomizationTool.resize(loadedImage, CustomizationTool.selectButtonDimension, CustomizationTool.selectButtonDimension);

    // break the inputed word into characters
    wordList = CustomizationTool.loadWord(loadedImage);

    // loop through each character to crop the character from the file and resize it
    for(int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) 

        wordList.set(i, CustomizationTool.resize(
                CustomizationTool.cropToFit(inputImage), CustomizationTool.selectButtonDimension, CustomizationTool.selectButtonDimension));


    selectButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(inputImage));

    // fill the base variables in the lists for the input image
    fillMatchingPixels();

} catch (IOException error) {

    System.out.println("input file does not exsist");

}
```

I tried to print the transparency values using `Color.getAlpha()`. However, I got 255 as a result, which means it is completely opaque.

Comment: It's not clear from your code what is your actual problem. If your problem is that you're not getting the expected value immediately after loading the image, then you don't need all the rest of the code about cropping - you need to post the *minimal* code to reproduce the problem. Which would include *how* you determine the color value, and also a sample image that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: To help with the MRE suggested by @ErwinBolwidt, either upload the image in question and hot-link to it, or use one of the images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).